# pacman implementing bfs for finding pacman path

Tags: c++

I am building a c++ pacman game using SFML.
I want to implement a BFS algorithm for finding the closest path to pacman, I am having trouble doing this and would appreciate help.
Basically I have a lot of inheritance.
I have a class of board which holds a vector of static objects(walls, cookies,and spaces)
I need to find the quickest way for ghost to get t pacman while being smart enough not to hit walls. 
thank you

Comment: Put your current project aside to experiment with BFS. Read. Research. If you have problems, you can ask here, but make sure you read the site guidelines.

Comment: I already have an idea, just don't know how to implement it in code

Comment: Start with expressing it in plain natural language instead.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, you probably want to represent your "game world" as a 2D grid instead of a collection of objects. You can fill the grid with the separate objects (walls etc). Then each cell can be either a wall/obstacle or an open space. From there you probably will have a better starting point to look into path finding algorithm (example)s such as BFS, A* etc. which are shown to work on these 2D grids.